# Errors Unity Keycode etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Errors: Invalid token If, UnityEngine.KeyCode is a 'method' but is used like a 'type', UnityEngine.KeyCode.Equals is a 'type' but is used like a 'Variable'

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I));
    {
        hideCheatGUI = true;
    }
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Equals));
```

I need help fixing it. (I'm new so understand if I ask "noob" questions).

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the semicolons after your if statements. There you are not able to enter in any of those conditions.

Also, put your second if statement in your Update function. There, you put it outside.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {
        hideCheatGUI = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Equals))
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```